# How to read an UDP package and convert it to matrix that i can FFT?

Tags: python, numpy, fft, ethernet

What do I need to do with `p1` for FFT to work?

```
from numpy.fft import fft  
p1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)   
p1.recvfrom(1040)  
mat = fft(p1)
```

Comment: You need to start by reading the documentation for the UDP based protocol you are using to figure out how the data is formatted.

Comment: @Krumelur If i know what byte carries what information, how can i separate them, and arrange them in matrix?

Comment: Well, any answer to that question would depend knowing that. How is the data serialized? Raw binary? JSON? Protobuf? XML?

Comment: @Krumelur It is raw binary in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack a byte stream into a Python data structure with the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library. You'll need to represent the incoming stream using the format characters that correspond with the C data types in the data. For example, if you knew that your input stream was a series of 5 unsigned ints represented as 4 bytes, you could use

```
struct.unpack('hhhhh', p1[0])
```

(the [recvfrom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom) documentation says that it returns a tuple of (string, address), where string is the data received).

This would return a tuple of 5 integers. From my understanding, a list of tuples is valid input for `numpy.fft`, but of course you can preprocess the tuples however you need to before you feed it to numpy.